# switch to dark theme in youtrack like available when logged out

Tags: jetbrains-ide, youtrack

I experienced a feature where you can switch to dark theme in Youtrack when u open a task which is public and you are **logged** in.

[image]

Any idea how to use this when logged in? Can not find the option for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the tumbler should be in the same place as for guest users:
[image]

Don't you have it? Could you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: is it available in youtrack cloud?

Comment: sure, it is available for the InCloud.

Comment: I haven't been able to find it

Comment: The location of this button has been changed recently. Please navigate to the issue page and click on your avatar in the right upper corner - you should be able to see a tumbler in the opened popup.